# Why do GraphQL Subscriptions use an AsyncIterator?

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-subscriptions

`AsyncIterator` requires pulling data using `.next()`. But with websockets I generally want to push data when events occur. Only thing I can think of is that by using pull-based they can rate-limit.

So what is calling `.next()`? Is it a timer, or does it listen to a publish message, queue that, then call `.next()` until it consumes all the queue?

Is this suitable for real-time data, like GPS positions on a map?

Looked here and still could not figure it out: https://github.com/facebook/graphql/blob/master/rfcs/Subscriptions.md

GraphQL Subscriptions repo from Apollo: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncIterator` iterate through an `EventStream`, then each event is resolved, sometimes with filter and/or with a payload manipulation.

Payload manipulation can call an another async database request, or resolve other GraphQL Types, which is time consuming.

So GraphQL use a pull-based system to rate-limit resolves eventStream. If you don't use `withFilter` neither `resolves`, you won't have delay on Event except with a lot of user.

GraphQL is suitable for low latency data.

Source: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/subscription/subscribe.js#L44